# Lilypond spacing between lyrics and next system

Tags: sheet-music, lilypond

I’m trying to improve the legibility of my scores by increasing the basic-distance between systems. There needs to be some whitespace between the last verse and the next system below.

Here's what I’ve tried so far

```
nonstaff-unrelatedstaff-spacing.basic-distance = #18
```

=> does not work between systems, but only staves in the same system.

```
system-system-spacing.basic-distance = #14
```

=> increases the basic distance between the staves that are facing each other across systems, but does not include the lyrics between them. I would thus have to increase the distance depending on the number of verses.

I am also not sure, where to put the lines. Mostly I’ve placed them in a `\paper` block at the top of the file

```
\paper {
  system-system-spacing.basic-distance = #18
}
```

but I have also tried putting them in layout in the lyrics’ context

```
\score {
  \layout {
    \context { \Lyrics
      \override VerticalAxisGroup.nonstaff-unrelatedstaff-spacing.basic-distance = #18
    }
  }
  %{ … %}
}
```

this did not yield any noticeably different results from the above examples.

[image: example]

Any pointers would be welcome, all this seems like an oversight to me but I am starting to get the feeling that nobody has thought about this so far. I'd be happy to help filing an issue with the dev team, should it come to that.

edit: Using `padding` instead of `basic-distance` solved the problem.

[image: correct spacing]

Comment: Possible kludge: add a whitespace-only line above and below the existing text block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If something like what you have posted is not working, it may be because your instructions are attempting to reference a part of your score that you haven't spelled out (that is, while you may be attempting to put space between systems, with lyrics below them, maybe your score isn't structured that way).

For instance: (code here: http://lilybin.com/36udgm/1)

```
\version "2.18.2"
\paper {
  system-system-spacing = #'((padding . 20))
}
melody = \relative c' {
  \repeat unfold 12 { 
    b'4 b b b
  }
}
words = \lyricmode {
  \repeat unfold 12 {
    Lor -- em ip -- sum
  }
}
\score {
  <<
    \new ChoirStaff <<
      \new Voice = "sing" { \melody }
      \new Lyrics \lyricsto sing \words
      \new Lyrics \lyricsto sing \words
      \new Lyrics \lyricsto sing \words
      \new Lyrics \lyricsto sing \words
      \new Voice = "sing" { \melody }
    >>
      \new Lyrics \lyricsto sing \words
      \new Lyrics \lyricsto sing \words
      \new Lyrics \lyricsto sing \words
      \new Lyrics \lyricsto sing \words
  >>
}
```

[image]

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I think I see what you mean. It has to be independent of the number of verses. I'll compile a visual example to illustrate.

Comment: After playing around with your example I realised that my mistake has been to use `basic-distance` instead of `padding`, works perfectly now, thank you.

Comment: @JoëlMeyer-Hamme - Try reading through here: http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/flexible-vertical-spacing-paper-variables#structure-of-flexible-vertical-spacing-alists for an explanation on the other options --- I have always used `padding` because I don't understand their definitions of most of the others.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, here are all the parameters for that function, with their default values:

```
system-system-spacing =
  #'((basic-distance . 12) 
     (minimum-distance . 8)
     (padding . 1)
     (stretchability . 60))
```